# Is this a infinite loop? why?

Tags: javascript

I was playing arround with some code and did this code that appears to be a infinit loop but I don't know why.

```
let battery = 100;
let hackedTerminals = 0;
const welcomeMessage = 'fSociety distro is booting... Please enter your 
username: ';
const username = 'Samuel';

console.log(welcomeMessage + username);

const batteryLeft = () =>{
  battery ? console.log('I\'ve still got ' + battery + '% battery. Let\'s hack some more targets!'):
  console.log('I\'m out of battery. I was able to hack ' + hackedTerminals + 'termonals.')
}

const totalTries = 3;
let attempts = 0;
const failedAttemptMessage = 'Wrong password... Keep trying, Hackerman!';
let wipedData = false;
```

Here the infinite loop

```
function tryHack(){
  attempts++
  if (attempts >= 3){
    wipedData = true;
  }else{
    wipedData = false;
  }
  wipedData ? console.log('All data has been deleted!'):
  console.log(failedAttemptMessage)
 tryHack()
}
```

tryHack()

Comment: Use the JavaScript debugger in your browser and find out …?

Comment: Uhm… you're *unconditionally* calling `tryHack()` again at the end of `tryHack`…?! That's why?

Comment: The trick to understanding why it loops (actually, it recurses) is to ask yourself "when is it supposed to end the function instead of calling the function again?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your function `tryHack` inside `tryHack` unconditionally which makes it call itself infinitely, so your code produces a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54350333/1419590) (Which is an error that happens when the [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack) exceeds its bound)